# Dual formulation of a QCLP

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, duality-theorems, bilinear-form, qclp

I'm working on a quadratic constrained linear program (QCLP) which I'm trying to obtain its dual formulation. I would like this formulation to be linear, or at least convex. Here are my results so far.

Let $q_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a column vector of parameters, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be the vector of decision variables, $Q\in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$ be a positive semidefinite matrix, and $p \in \mathbb{R}$ a constant. The primal formulation of the problem is,

$$ \min q_0^t x $$
subject to
$$ x^t Q x + p \leq 0 : \lambda$$
where $\lambda$ is the dual variable associated to the conic constraint.
To obtain the dual formulation I write the Lagrangian function $\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda)$ as $\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda) = q_0^t x + \lambda(x^t Q x + p)$. Then the dual function $D(\lambda)$ is

$$ D(\lambda) = \inf_x \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda) $$

which can be found reorganising terms from the lagrangian function as follows
$$ D(\lambda) = \lambda p + \inf_x (q_0^t + \lambda x^t Q)x = \begin{cases} \lambda p \quad \text{if} \quad q_0^t + \lambda x^t Q = 0 \\ -\infty \quad \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Making the equality explicit, the dual problem is
$$ \max \lambda p$$
subject to
$$ q_0 + Q^t x \lambda = 0 \\ \lambda \geq 0 $$

The term $Q^t x \lambda$ is bilinear as it contains primal and dual variables. Is there a way to get a dual problem with linear or convex constraints? Or have I made a mistake in the derivation?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think that your expression of $D(\lambda)$ is wrong. It should not contain the variable $x$, since there is an infimum over $x$ in the definition of $D(\lambda)$.

Comment: The thing is that I've also tried to use  $\nabla_x \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda) = 0$, which gives $x = -\frac{1}{2\lambda}Q^{-1}q_0^t$ assuming $Q$ symmetric. Then I plug that into $D(\lambda)$, but then $\lambda$ cancel out which leaves the infimum as  $\inf_x (q_0^t -\frac{1}{2}Q^{-1}q_0Q)x$ which is $-\infty$.